Render Material Ruined by Blender 3.4 upgrade to 4.2
A large project I have been working on is near completed. I am on my final rendering of my last model and for some reason every single blender file on my computer is now a 4.2 file, even tho I have been working with them in 3.4 for over a month now.
As a result, my render material is now broken, my renders have lines going through them and the lighting is absolutely off.
Is there any way to revert my files back to 3.4?

Have you saved from 4.2 and overwritten the old ones with the new version?

An older version doesn't just magically save in future format. In any case, there should be autosaves that you can access from File menu -> Recover -> Auto Save... . By default Blender also saves .blend1 file when you save. That is the previous save, so you can rename the extension or just open those files in Blender. If you saved multiple times from a newer version without making sure the files are fully compatible... well... that's a very unpleasant mistake... that YOU made.

No it is unfortunately not a mistake I made. I just reviewed files from over a year ago, and sure enough they all say 4.2 and all of their rendering materials and lighting is broken. The only files that were safe were files that were compressed into zips, when I extract them and open with 3.4 they are fine. Everything that was NOT in a zip is now a 4.2 file type and borked. NOT and mistake I made in fact.
We are talking about HUNDREDS of blender files on my computer all updated to 4.2 and even when opening in 3.4 they are already compromised.

They all "say" 4.2, meaning ? if you go in the outliner,  "data API" mode, unroll "version", it says 4.2 ?

I was able to extract an 3.4 file from an old zip and append the materials and lighting into one of the 3.4 files that was damaged and marked 4.2 (even tho ver is 3.4 when opening in text doc) and salvage my work for this project.
Something strange certainly happened and I believe it has to do with windows default program and my %temp% files I cleared out yesterday.

By "they say 4.2" I mean file type in windows, however when opening them with text editor they say 3.4 still.

The version of a blend file is indicated where I said just above. Windows explorer just shows you the default program associated with those files. It doesn't mean they have been saved with this version.

Correct, I have also launched my previous files manually to 3.4 and yet they are still borked.
Yesterday they said 3.4, today 4.2 next to the file type
Im sure its just windows default application like you mentioned, however I can no longer open them in 3.4 without them being bugged.
for over a month I have been working with 3.4 and 4.2 respectively.
I believe it was clearing out my %Temp% files yesterday that caused this issue to occur.
ALl of my files are now acting as if they are 4.2 which is where I discovered my material and lighting doesnt currently work in.

When I discovered this issues early last month, I simply continued working in 3.4
But not ALL of my files have this issue now, even when opening in 3.4 This is when I noticed file type was updated. Even on files from years ago.

It is still a bit unclear what you are doing there. What do you mean you "can no longer open them in 3.4 without them being bugged"? Have you opened them in 4.2 and saved them in this new version? A 3.4 file will not automatically become a 4.2 file if you do not save it with 4.2, so if you did that unfortunately @MartynasŽiemys is right, that's a mistake you made. We also do not know what you have in those files in detail - some things have changed, some have not. If a file contains only things that work in both versions it may not seem broken, while others simply get messed up.

.blend files are not marked with any version information in any way recognizable by Windows OS.
As you can see I have .blend files in various Blender versions I happen to have saved in one folder:

You can clearly see that they are all recognized as "Type Blender 4.3". This is because Blender 4.3 is the version I registered as software to open .blend files in my Windows. That's all. That does not mean anything else at all.
You can find out the version of file format by opening the file, going to the Outliner and setting it to Data API display mode. You will be able to view Version there:

Note that this is not Blender's version, but the version of the file format. X and Y numbers usually are a good indication of what Blender version was used to save the file. As you can see, my file's version is 4.3.32 even though the Blender version I use is 4.3.0 - that's normal, because file data version and Blender version are different things apparently.
You can just open Blender version that you want and then open the files from that Blender using File -> Open and they should open fine if you use the correct Blender version matching the file's version. Unless of course you made the unfortunate mistake and did save the files when opened in the newer version. In newer Blender versions there is also a choice to quickly register the currently open Blender version as Default in the OS:

You can of course use the OS features to set default software to open .blend file type or you could look into this Blender Launcher program that people seem to recommend for working with multiple versions, but I haven't tried it myself so I have no idea what it really does or if it's worth it - decide for yourself.

I'm using Blender Launcher, cool little piece of software - though it weighs 50 MB + another 46 MB for the updater, perhaps they use Electron, ugh.
